# How to run jenkins with old version of Java instead the latest default one on MacOS?

Tags: macos, jenkins, macos-high-sierra

I'm setting up Jenkins on my Macbook (High Sierra), seems like the default version of Java is Java 9, which causes issue "java.lang.AssertionError: InstanceIdentity is missing its singleton"

I changed the Java home of my Mac from 9.x to 8 already, but when I reinstall, same trouble still comes along.

I checked the System Properties under Manage Jenkins/System Information, the value java.specification.version still is "9".

So how can I install Jenkins with old version of Java?
Or any workaround for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what worked for me with OS X 10.13.2 (High Sierra).

1. I used "brew install jenkins" to install Jenkins. You can find instructions from http://flummox-engineering.blogspot.com/2016/01/installing-jenkins-os-x-homebrew.html,  for example.
2. Download JDK 8 from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
3. Set your JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME to point to the version you downloaded. (Put this is your .bash_profile if needed.)
   For example,
   export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home
   export JDK_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home
4. Type in "jenkins --httpPort=9898" or whatever port is desired to start Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't using the brew installation, you can open the start script at

`/Library/Application Support/Jenkins/jenkins-runner.sh`

and set your JAVA_HOME at the top of the script using the following line

```
export JAVA_HOME="`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`"
```

Then restart Jenkins and you'll be running Jenkins on 1.8